Printer sharing in Ubuntu 24.04
How do I share a printer on an ethernet LAN using Ubuntu 24.04.  Both computers have a fresh install of 24.04 and are connected to the Internet with ethernet cables but only one is connected to the printer with a USB cable.

That was the usual procedure in 22.04 but it does not appear to be possible in 24.04

There is no longer an option to share printers in Ubuntu 24.04 like there was in 22.04 (as well as previous versions).  It was located in Settings->Printers but not in the 24.04 release.  Settings->Sharing only concerns itself with media sharing.  Perhaps I am looking in the wrong areas.

Try this old school method:
Use the web interface for CUPS
Using the computer with the printer, open a browser (Firefox) and enter the URL: localhost:631. This will open the CUPS printer page. Select the Administration tab at the top.
Enter your username and sudo password for the computer.

Check the box next to Share printers connected to this system. Then click the button Change Settings.
If this does not work, try the next step.
Go the Printers tab above. You should see your printer listed. Select your printer under the column labeled Queue Name.
From the Administration pull down menu, select Set as Server Default.

Now you have to setup the other Ubuntu computer to connect to the network printer associated with the IP address of the computer connected to the USB printer.
Hope this helps

Sorry I couldn't get back to you sooner.  The boss said put the darn printer between the two computers and plug it in as needed.  Thank you for your solution.

Of course your solution worked.  I was able to test it even after the move.  Marked it as a solution.  Thank you.

Thanks for confirming that the solution works.
